# Unable to locate vendor files using electron with angular2 and angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, angular-cli

I have created a sample hero app (the app in the quick-start) using angular-cli, and it works as intended.

`npm start` comes up with my app, working as intended.

However, launching the app in electron seems to be failing miserably. For the life of me can not seem to figure out why electron is not able to find the folders contained within `dist/`.

I.e. my `dist/` directory has the following:

[image: pretty standard...]

However, when I start `electron dist/` (which contains `index.js` the electron main file), the console outputs the following:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js Failed to load resource:
```

But clearly they are in the `vendor/` directory, since my `npm start` is working correctly.

My `index.js` is pretty much a copy of getting started:

```
const electron = require('electron');
// Module to control application life.
const {app} = electron;
// Module to create native browser window.
const {BrowserWindow} = electron;

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);


  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null;
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get your application to work with the file:// protocol, you need to do the following:

Inside of src/index.html, change the following line as follows:

From:

```
<base href="/">
```

To

```
<base href="./">
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Also, forgot to mention: If you are running your app both online and offline, you might want to use some sort of detection, so that you can switch back to the / base when the app is running inside a normal browser window, via HTTP.

Comment: yep this was the reason. i just ended up deleting base href...didnt seem to impact it

Answer (score 1):

With the latest angular-cli version, you need to pass the base href path as an argument to the ng build command instead of changing it in the index.html file:

```
ng build --base-href .
```

Hope it helps.